# Show Pixel ruler in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, pixels

I use Visual Studio 2013 and want to use a Pixel ruler in the designer.

I saw some screenshots on the internet but don't know how to display the ruler or if I have to install a plugin or something.

Comment: As an aside, I use jRuler (it's free). Simply because I use the ruler for web design as well. Unless you need a ruler to to always be present (and on simultanious X and Y axis) then this may suffice.

Comment: @Dave I think the OP is using Windows Forms in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2013:

- Select Tools > Options
- Window Form Designer > General
- Set "Layout Mode" to "SnapToGrid"
- Set "Show Grid" to "True" (by default this is True)
- Click OK, close and reopen the form in the designer

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried it, but I do not see any ruler.

Comment: Did you see the grid? I don't recall anything like a traditional ruler you might see in Word in any version of Visual Studio I've used. The grid serves as a ruler for most purposes, but you may be looking for something else.

Comment: No, I see no grid either although I set *Show Grid* to `true`

Comment: The grid is off by default in VS 2013 and after doing the above the grid should be displayed. Don't forget to close the form and re-open (or restart Visual Studio itself).

Comment: Even restarting didn't help. No grid.

Comment: @juergend The "grid" the answer is referring to is not shown all the time, it's only shown when you move a control near another one; I wouldn't even really call it a grid, I'd call it "alignment lines" or something.